# javascript function needs doubleclick to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have these two javascript functions that for some reason I have to click the button twice for them to work. any ideas?

```
var shirts = new Array("shirtpink.png","shirtred.png", "shirtblue.png", "shirtyellow.png","shirt.png");

var index = 0;
function changecolor(){
    if (index > 4){
        index = 0;
    }
    var shirtpick = document.getElementById("shirt");
    shirtpick.setAttribute('src',shirts[index]);
    index++;
}
```

other function:

```
function changecolorback(){
    index--;
    i++;
    if (index < 0){
        index = 4;
    }
    var shirtback = document.getElementById("shirt");
    shirtback.setAttribute('src',shirts[index]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an HTML example of how these functions are called.

Comment: Can you paste the html code too?

Comment: okay, so you could fix this or you could just use jQuery.

Comment: "just use jQuery" makes me very tired.

Comment: I can program in native JavaScript, I can understand mechanics, I can code using jQuery. If you're tired, go take a nap; and if you can't sleep, stop coding in jQuery and continue coding in native JS.

Comment: @pixelbobby : http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif, so sorry, but loading jquery just for a doubleclickevent?

Comment: Lol, work blocked it but i'll check it later when I get home :] I'm sure it's of equal sarcasm or better. Cheers.  p.s. I agree w/ you.

Comment: @Peter, you should add a disclaimer that that is not genuine - it could give a bad (although hilarious) wrap on the community

Comment: @davin : isn't that obvious? People even lose 10kg using jquery :-) I'm afraid it's no longer editable, but the disclaimer was made by you already

Answer (score 5):

```
var shirts = ["shirtpink.png","shirtred.png", "shirtblue.png", "shirtyellow.png","shirt.png"],
    index = 0;

function changecolor(amount){
   index = (index + amount) % shirts.length;
   document.getElementById("shirt").setAttribute('src',shirts[index]);
}
```

The reason was your increments:
You were incrementing after your code executed (in one function, but not in the other, so your `changecolorback()` should have behaved ok).

You also had `i++` which looked redundant, and some variables that were only used once.

I shortened your code (drastically) so you get to these comments without too much scrolling.
Instead of calling `changecolorback()`, you can now just do `changecolor(-1)`, and the forward method is `changecolor(1)`.

Another advantage is that this will allow you to jump by more than one, or a random amount, which might (or might not) be useful.

**EDIT:**

JS implements modulus like Java, so negatives still hold their sign. I.e. `(-1)%5 === -1`

You can overcome this pretty easily by changing (more elegant although not quite equivalent):

```
index = Math.abs(index + amount) % shirts.length;
```

or

```
index = ((index + amount) % shirts.length + shirts.length ) % shirts.length;
```

Comment: the changecolor(1) works fine except the fact that it skips the first element but goes to it the second time it goes through the array.  and the changecolor(-1) gives me an undefined array error. I fixed it by adding this line  if (index == -1){index = 4;} but I have to click it twice again

Comment: @user, with my update there should no longer be an undefined error array. If it skips the first element, then set the initial value to `-1`. If all of this still isn't enough, then the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try incrementing/decrementing index at the beginning of both functions.  Also, you have 5 elements, not 4 in your array.  You should probably use `shirts.length` to avoid this.